# Failure to parse file & session aborted when reading large stata file

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a 1.2 GB (compressed) stata file or 2.4 GB stata file. Both are .dta. I'm using a 128 GB RAM shared windows VPS.

My code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/ash/Desktop/GWL Ash")

install.packages("haven")
library("haven")

memory.limit()
#memory.limit(size = 9999999900000)


gwl <- read_dta("NewGWLfullcomp.dta")
```

When I try to read the 2.4 GB stata file, I get the error below

```
Error: Failed to parse C:/Users/ash/Desktop/Ash GWL/NewGWLfull.dta: Unable to allocate memory.
```

When I try to read the 1.2 GB stata file, I get the error below

```
R session aborted, R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated"
```

I tried increasing the memory limit using the code below but I still get the errors. I tried both RStudio and RGUI, both give the same errors.

```
memory.limit(size = 9999999900000)
```

R.version output:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 14393)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

Comment: I don't know what you should do in this case. I think it is too big of a file. How much RAM does your system have in comparison?

Comment: I'm using a 128 RAM VPS. It's a shared VPS but I doubt there's many people using it.

Comment: Can you report back the `R.version`? I want to see if you're on Win32.

Comment: Also, can you set the new limit via `memory.limit(size = 6000)` then see if the limit was granted, by using `memory.size()`. If so, then try to run the reading function once more.

Comment: I'm using windows 64. The limit was granted. I'm using R version 1.2.5033, I'll ask my system admin if I can download the latest update (2021.09.0+351)

Comment: It's not really RStudio. RStudio does nearly nothing, but R does everything. 
Can You put up the `R.version` output?

Comment: I put the r.version output on the end of my post.

Comment: Thanks. Can you include a `sessionInfo()` as well? There are several issues on github that reports this as well, see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/342)

Comment: I added the sessioninfo. Thanks for the link. I may downgrade to haven 1.1.0 since people are saying that's what helped them.

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to see what version of `{haven}` you've got installed. The issue refers to an old version, you might have an old version installed or something to that effect.